# Why can't my circle and text exit and remove at same time

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I use `setInterval` to update my data: `setInterval(function() { update(nextDay(data)) }, 10);` All circle, lines and text entered at same time, but can not exit at same time. 
Here I entered text twice because I need display two different kinds of text at the can I call twice `enter()` to text in a same svg?
and here is my update function:

```
function update(data){

    var bcircle = group.selectAll('circle').data(data)
    bcircle.enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) {coords = projection([d.long,d.lat]); return  coords[0]})
        .attr('cy', function(d) {coords = projection([d.long,d.lat]); return  coords[1]})
        .attr('r',  function(d) { return countScale(d.count)})
        .attr("stroke", function(d, i) { return color(d.name, i);}) 
        .attr("stroke-width", 2.3)
        .style('fill', function(d) { 
                if (d.count == 0){ return 'white';}
                if (d.count !== 0){ return color(d.name);}
            });
    bcircle.exit().remove();

    var btime = group.selectAll('line').data(data)
    btime.enter().append("line")
        .attr('x1', function(d) {return timeScale(d.time)})
        .attr("x2", function(d) {return timeScale(d.time)})
        .attr("y1", lineHeight+5)               
        .attr("y2", lineHeight-5)
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("stroke-width", "5"); 
    btime.exit().remove();  

    var timelb = group.selectAll("text").data(data)
    timelb.enter().append("text")
            .attr('x', function(d) {return timeScale(d.time)})
        .attr('y', lineHeight+20)
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {return time2label(d.time)})
        // .attr("font-family", 'sans-serif')
        // .attr("font-size", 19 + "px")
        // .attr("fill", 'black');      
    timelb.exit().remove();

    timelb.enter().append("text")
        .attr('x', function(d) {coords = projection([d.long,d.lat]); return  coords[0]+20})
        .attr('y', function(d) {coords = projection([d.long,d.lat]); return  coords[1]-5})
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name + ":" + d.count; })
        .attr("font-family", 'sans-serif')
        .attr("font-size", 19 + "px")
        .attr("fill", 'black'); 
    timelb.exit().remove();
}
```

Comment: there's no argument in your `update` function definition, but you're passing one in `setinterval`

Comment: There is, sorry I forgot add it in.

Comment: Okay. I, for one, can't really understand your question. From your perspective it might make sense, but we don't know the context of your problem and we don't even know what your page is suppose to look like. What do you mean they are all "entered" at the same time? What do you mean "exit"? If you can, try making a copy of your page on jsfiddle.net, so that we can see what you're doing and what's going wrong.

Comment: here is all my code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeReMi/unFyq/725/. But I don't know how to load external data file, do it can not display something. Some circles will be displayed, but can not removed correctly after I update. I think I got something wrong on my exit().remove().

Comment: Have you verified that your exit selection contains what you think it does?